Query Related to shiv purana
I recently happened to read shiv purana and couldn't digest that Lord Vishnu was a womanizer and even had sex with his own aunt named Radha. This has been used against Hindus to target them which happens quite often in Tamil Nādu and I saw a twitteratti doing it. Was Vishnu really a sex addict ? can you quote some references. I will happily take it if it has a meaning.

What? Could you give a chapter no. Etc.? I'd like to check this claim.

could you provide the verse here is the shiva purana  plz give the  section chapter and verse you have problem in

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
